# Is it possible to host a ServiceStack project in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions, servicestack

Is it possible to host a ServiceStack app in an Azure Functions?  I can't find anyone even asking if this is possible.  Is it a terrible idea?

Comment: If it is no matter with UI, you can do it.

Comment: As ServiceStack is registered as a [regular ASP .NET Core Module](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#binding-to-net-core) with minimal .NET Standard 2.0 dependencies, there shouldn't be any issues with running it on Azure Functions.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to do this? As far as I can see the only entry point for Azure Functions is `public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)`, doesn't seem compatible with the full Service _Stack_

Comment: No, I wasn't able to make it work either.

Comment: @mythz could you please give a bit more info? As far as I can see the only entry point for Azure Functions is `public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)`, doesn't seem compatible with the full Service _Stack_

Comment: @rockgecko I've no experience with Azure functions, I just expect it to be able to run [ASP .NET Core Middleware like AWS lambda's can](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/), if that's not supported then it's not going to be able to run any ASP .NET Core middleware which is ASP .NET Core's fundamental API for composing features in an ASP .NET Core App & what ServiceStack uses. If AF doesn't support this core API it's going to be incompatible with all ASP .NET Core App features.